# How to control version of zip dependencies?

Tags: bower

I'm doing a Proof of Concept with Bower, and trying to create packages without using Git (this is a requirement). I have two packages:

**core** - main package

**datetime** - depends on core

In `bower.json` we declare the version of the package, why the install create an e-tag instead?

Example of install command:

```
bower install http://path.to.package/core-0.0.1.zip
```

If I run `bower list` I can see it (ommited some other dependencies):

```
├── angular#1.3.12 (1.4.0-build.3831+sha.056a317 available)
├─┬ angular-animate#1.3.12 (1.4.0-build.3831+sha.056a317 available)
│ └── angular#1.3.12 (latest is 1.4.0-build.3831+sha.056a317)
├─┬ angular-cookies#1.3.12 (1.4.0-build.3831+sha.056a317 available)
│ └── angular#1.3.12
├─┬ angular-mocks#1.3.12 (1.3.14-build.49+sha.6b7625a available, latest is 1.4.0
-build.3831+sha.056a317)
│ └── angular#1.3.12
├─┬ angular-resource#1.3.12 (1.4.0-build.3831+sha.056a317 available)
│ └── angular#1.3.12
├─┬ angular-route#1.3.12 (1.4.0-build.3831+sha.056a317 available)
│ └── angular#1.3.12
├─┬ angular-sanitize#1.3.12 (1.4.0-build.3831+sha.056a317 available)
│ └── angular#1.3.12
├─┬ angular-scenario#1.3.12 (1.3.14-build.49+sha.6b7625a available, latest is 1.
4.0-build.3831+sha.056a317)
│ └── angular#1.3.12
├─┬ angular-touch#1.3.12 (1.4.0-build.3831+sha.056a317 available)
│ └── angular#1.3.12
├─┬ bootstrap-sass-official#3.3.3
│ └── jquery#2.0.3 (2.1.3 available)
├── es5-shim#4.1.0
├── json3#3.3.2
├─┬ core#e-tag:53d7d65924
│ ├─┬ angular-strap#0.7.4 (latest is 2.1.6)
│ │ ├── bootstrap#2.3.2 (3.3.2 available)
│ │ ├─┬ bootstrap-datepicker#1.3.1
│ │ │ ├── bootstrap#2.3.2 incompatible with >=3.0 <4.0 (3.3.2 available)
│ │ │ └── jquery#2.0.3 (2.1.3 available)
│ │ ├─┬ bootstrap-select#1.6.3 (2.0.0-beta1 available)
│ │ │ └── jquery#2.0.3 (2.1.3 available)
│ │ ├─┬ bootstrap-timepicker#0.2.6
│ │ │ ├── autotype#e-tag:4fc86fb68
│ │ │ ├── bootstrap#2.3.2 (latest is 3.3.2)
│ │ │ └── jquery#2.0.3 (2.1.3 available)
│ │ └── jquery#2.0.3 (2.1.3 available)
└── datetime#e-tag:4c585cbc3e extraneous
```

How can I install zip packages and control the dependencies with version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bower is currently ignoring the version property specified in bower.json, for more info see the bower.json [specification](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec#version).
When resolving a package from a URL and an *ETag* header is present in the response, Bower will store the value of this header in the package metadata. When checking if a new version of the package is available, Bower will use the cache ETag (by sending a If-None-Match header).
Notice that Bower's support for working with URL target is limited and is not a drop-in replacement for working with Git. For further details take a look at [UrlResolver.js](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/lib/core/resolvers/UrlResolver.js).

Comment: I saw that SVN have a resolver too, but there's any another alternative? The organization use TFS, maybe with a custom resolver, is this possible?

Comment: @SérgioMichels There is an effort to create a pluggable resolver architecture. See https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1649

Comment: Sounds really good. So the final answer is: in the future it will be possible to do it, but for now I don't have an alternative, is that correct?